# Resolving "not found" messages after doing ./configure building node.js

Tags: debian

Hello I am trying to install node.js on debian AMD64.

I got node.js from git.

When I do ./configure a bunch of "checking for program" messages say "not found".  I want to resolve all these and ensure everything needed is present.  Can anyone suggest what I need to do to resolve the "not found" messages?  Thanks heaps.

server:/devel/node# ./configure

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++

Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp

Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar

Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib

Checking for g++                         : ok

Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc

Checking for gcc                         : ok

Checking for library dl                  : yes

Checking for library execinfo            : not found

Checking for openssl                     : not found

Checking for function SSL_library_init   : yes

Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : yes

Checking for library rt                  : yes

--- libeio ---

Checking for library pthread             : yes

Checking for function pthread_create     : yes

Checking for function pthread_atfork     : yes

Checking for futimes(2)                  : yes

Checking for readahead(2)                : yes

Checking for fdatasync(2)                : yes

Checking for pread(2) and pwrite(2)      : yes

Checking for sendfile(2)                 : yes

Checking for sync_file_range(2)          : yes

--- libev ---

Checking for header sys/inotify.h        : yes

Checking for function inotify_init       : yes

Checking for header sys/epoll.h          : yes

Checking for function epoll_ctl          : yes

Checking for header port.h               : not found

Checking for header poll.h               : yes

Checking for function poll               : yes

Checking for header sys/event.h          : not found

Checking for header sys/queue.h          : yes

Checking for function kqueue             : not found

Checking for header sys/select.h         : yes

Checking for function select             : yes

Checking for header sys/eventfd.h        : not found

Checking for SYS_clock_gettime           : yes

Checking for library rt                  : yes

Checking for function clock_gettime      : yes

Checking for function nanosleep          : yes

Checking for function ceil               : yes

Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : yes

'configure' finished successfully (1.479s)
server:/devel/node#

Answer (score 3):

Not all of them can be fixed, since the script is checking for OS support. The one that matters is OpenSSL, for which you install `apt-get install libdev-ssh` or something similar.

Also, to avoid false positives for the openssl check you need to have pkg-config installed using `apt-get install pkg-config` or the like.

Comment: How do I know if these "not found" messages matter?  I would have thought that the application being built needs all the stuff that it is checking for.....or is this assumption wrong?

Comment: It's something you learn with experience. In general a "not found" isn't fatal unless the configure script says it is.

Comment: I've tried the following 

apt-get install openssl
apt-get install openssl-dev
apt-get install openssl-devel
apt-get install libssl
apt-get install libssl-dev
apt-get install libssl-devel

And I still get the same openssl not found when running ./configure

Any further ideas on what I could do to resolve the "not found" for openssl? thanks

Comment: Read config.log, and find out which test is failing and why.

Comment: Thanks! the config.log file revealed that pkg-config was not found.  I installed it with 

apt-get install pkg-config 

now ./configure no longer says "not found" for openssl.

I still feel uncomfortable with the following "not found" messages - the perfectionist in me wants everything to be right. 

Checking for library execinfo            : not found 
Checking for header port.h               : not found 
Checking for header sys/event.h          : not found 
Checking for function kqueue             : not found 
Checking for header sys/eventfd.h        : not found 

But i trust you are right.

Comment: To put it in perspective, kqueue is found in *BSD and Darwin, so there's no way you can fulfill all the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have kqueue because you're on debian GNU/Linux and kqueue is a BSD-only kernel facility.

You would have it if you built node.js on FreeBSD, for example.